# N-th Derivative of $\sin(x)/x$

Tags: calculus

How would one go about obtaining a closed form for the $n$-th derivative of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ I took a few of the derivatives but didn't see any immediate pattern.

There may be some obvious thing I'm missing, or overthinking it.

Comment: Use Leibniz' formula, but you'll get a sum rather than a closed form.

Comment: Oh, I suppose that's a good point. That sum probably would have a known form, no?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you multiply both sides by $x$ first:
$$xf(x)=\sin x\ ,$$
then differentiate $k$ times, using Leibniz' rule on the LHS to get
$$xf^{(k)}(x)+kf^{(k-1)}(x)=\sin^{(k)}x\ .$$
If we add this up for $k$ from $0$ to $n$, after multiplying by carefully chosen coefficients,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\,\frac{n!}{k!}\,x^{k-1}(xf^{(k)}(x)+kf^{(k-1)}(x)
  =\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\,\frac{n!}{k!}\,x^{k-1}\sin^{(k)}x\ ;$$
and the LHS telescopes, evaluating to $x^nf^{(n)}(x)$, which I leave you to confirm for yourself.  Therefore
$$\eqalign{f^{(n)}(x)
  &=x^{-(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n+k}\,\frac{n!}{k!}\,x^k\sin^{(k)}x\cr
  &=(-1)^nn!\,x^{-(n+1)}\Bigl(\sin x-\frac{x}{1!}\cos x
    -\frac{x^2}{2!}\sin x+\frac{x^3}{3!}\cos x+{}\cr
  &\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdots+(-1)^n\,\frac{x^n}{n!}\sin^{(n)}x\Bigr)\ .\cr}$$
If you want any "more closed" form than this, I wish you good luck :)

Note however that the $\sin^{(n)}x$ term is not really a difficulty as it's always either $\pm\sin x$ or $\pm\cos x$.

Comment: But couldn't we at least represent the $k$-th derivative of $\sin(x)$ as $\sin(x + \frac{k \pi}{2}$?

Comment: Yes if you like!

Comment: @David: I also like the "move the denominator" trick, but in this case direct Leibniz works well.

Comment: very cool approach. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

By direct application of the Leibniz rule,

$$\left(e^{ix}\,x^{-1}\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk i^ke^{ix}(-1)^{n-k}(n-k)!x^{k-n-1}\\
=n!(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{i^ke^{ix}}{k!x^{n-k+1}}.$$

You take the imaginary part, which is made of alternating sines and cosines over increasing powers of $x$. At the same time, this solves for $\dfrac{\cos x}x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a closed integral formula.

$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\sin x}{x}
= \frac1{x^{n+1}}\int_0^xt^n\sin(t + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2)dt.
$$

We prove it by induction. The case $n = 0$ is immediate since
$\int_0^x\cos t dt = \sin x$. Suppose it is true for some number $n$,
then by the product rule.
$$
\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\frac{\sin x}{x}
= \frac1{x^{n+1}}x^n\sin(x + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2)
       -\frac{n+1}{x^{n+2}}\int_0^xt^n\sin(t + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2)dt.
$$
Now integration by parts yield that the rightmost term is equal to
$$
-\frac{n+1}{x^{n+2}}\left(
\left[\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\sin(t + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2\right]_0^x
-\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1t^{n+1}\cos(t + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}{2})dt
\right).
$$
Using the fact that
$\cos(t + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2) = \sin(t + (n + 2)\frac{\pi}2$, indeed
$\sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}2) = \cos(\theta), \forall\theta$, we simplify
to
$$
-\frac{\sin(x + (n + 1)\frac{\pi}2}{x} + \frac1{x^{n+2}}\int_0^1t^{n+1}\sin(t + (n + 2)\frac{\pi}{2})dt.
$$

This proves the formula.

Answer (score 0):

First note that

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^l}{{\rm d}x^l} \frac{1}{x} = (-1)^l\frac{l!}{x^{l+1}} \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^l}{{\rm d}x^l} \sin x = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{l/2}\sin x &,& l ~~{\rm even}\\
(-1)^{(l-1)/2}\cos x &,& l ~~{\rm odd}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n}\frac{\sin x}{x} &=&
\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \left(\frac{{\rm d}^{n-k}}{{\rm d}x^{n-k}}\frac{1}{x}\right) \left(\frac{{\rm d}^k}{{\rm d}x^k} \sin x\right) \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left((-1)^{n-k}\frac{(n-k)!}{x^{n-k+1}}\right) \left(\frac{{\rm d}^k}{{\rm d}x^k} \sin x\right) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{x^{n-k+1}} \left(\frac{{\rm d}^k}{{\rm d}x^k} \sin x\right) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{n!}{(2k)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-2k}}{x^{n-2k+1}} \left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2k}}{{\rm d}x^{2k}} \sin x\right) + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \frac{n!}{(2k+1)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-2k+1}}{x^{n-2k+2}} \left(\frac{{\rm d}^{2k+1}}{{\rm d}x^{2k+1}} \sin x\right)\\
&=& (-1)^nn! \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac{1}{x^{n-2k +1}}\sin x -(-1)^nn!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{1}{x^{n-2k+2}}\cos x
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taylor expansion:
$$y=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8).$$
Hence: 
$$\begin{align}y'=&-\frac{2}{3!}x+\frac{4}{5!}x^3-\frac{6}{7!}x^5+O(x^7);\\
y''=&-\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{4\cdot 3}{5!}x^2-\frac{6\cdot 5}{7!}x^4+O(x^6)\\
y'''=& \qquad \ \ \frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{5!}x-\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7!}x^3+O(x^5);\\
y^{(4)}=& \qquad \ \ \frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{5!}-\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{7!}x^2+O(x^4);\\
\vdots \end{align}$$
Or:$$\begin{align}y'=&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2k)x^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k+2)x^{2k+1}}{(2k+3)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!(2k+3)};\\
y''=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k+1)x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!(2k+3)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{(2k)!(2k+3)};\\
y'''=&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(2k)x^{2k-1}}{(2k)!(2k+3)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!(2k+5)};\\
y^{(4)}=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(2k+1)x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!(2k+5)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!(2k+5)};\\
\vdots\\
y^{(n)}=&(-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \rfloor}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k+\lfloor n/2-\lfloor n/2\rfloor\rfloor}}{(2k+\lfloor n/2-\lfloor n/2\rfloor\rfloor)!(2k+2\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor+1)},
\end{align}$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a floor function.

Comment: Original approach. Unfortunately, infinite series (which you could reverse-engineer to trigonometric functions).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this post is to detail the derivation for the $k$-th derivative of the following function evaluated at any $x \in \mathbb R$:

> $ f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \quad&\text{if $x \neq$ 0}\\1 \quad &\text{if $x=0$} \end{cases}$

If you just want the answer without all of the underlying work (for which there is a considerable amount):

For $\displaystyle x \neq 0: f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)$

For $\displaystyle x =0: f^{(n)}(0)=\begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{n+1} \quad&\text{ if $n$ is even} \\0 \quad &\text{ if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}$

---

Having stated the above results, we will now march forward with the derivation. The following post will be broken up into several sections. **First** we will show how we arrive at a 'good guess' for the $n$th derivative at $x \neq 0$. **Second** we will formally prove (via induction) that this guess is correct. **Third** we will prove (once again with induction) the formulas associated with the $n$th derivative at $x=0$, which will be broken up into several subsections to address different cases. Throughout these proofs, I will use $I^n(x)$ to denote $x^n$. Further, the notation $g^{(n)}$ is distinct from $g^n$ where the former denotes the $n$th derivative and the latter denotes the $n$th power. Finally, the third section will make use of Taylor polynomials (the number of L-Hopital iterations required to prove this otherwise is too unwieldy).

---

**SECTION ONE**

Suppose $x \neq 0$. Then $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \implies f(x)\cdot x = \sin(x)$. Noting that the left side of this expression is just two functions $f$ and $I$ (where $I$ is the identity function) multiplied together, it makes perfect sense to take the $k$-th derivative of the left side, which would give us: $[f\cdot I]^{(k)}(x)=\sin^{(k)}(x)$. In order to evaluate the left side, we can apply Leibniz's formula, which gives us:

\begin{align}&[f\cdot I]^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}f^{(i)}(x)\cdot I^{(k-i)}(x) \\&={k\choose0}f^{(0)}(x)I^{(k)}(x)+{k\choose1}f^{(1)}(x)I^{(k-1)}(x)+\cdots+{k\choose k-1}f^{(k-1)}(x)I^{(1)}(x)+{k\choose k}f^{(k)}(x)I^{(0)}(x)\end{align}

Obviously, for any $i  \gt 1: I^{(i)}(x)=0$, which means we have:

$$[f\cdot I]^{(k)}(x)=kf^{(k-1)}(x)+f^{(k)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(k)}(x) \quad (\dagger)$$

In this final expression, you will note that there is no immediate way to write $f^{(k)}(x)=\cdots$ without including $f^{(k-1)}$ in the right side. In light of this consider the following approach to find any $n$-th derivative of $f$. For an arbitrary $k$, we have proven $(\dagger)$. Let us now list out all $k$-th derivatives between (and including) $1$ and $n$. Specifically, we have:

\begin{align}&k=1:\quad &&f^{(0)}(x)+f^{(1)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(1)}(x) \\&k=2:\quad &&2f^{(1)}(x)+f^{(2)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(2)}(x)\\&k=3:\quad &&3f^{(2)}(x)+f^{(3)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(3)}(x)\\&k=4:\quad &&4f^{(3)}(x)+f^{(4)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(4)}(x)\\& \cdots \\&k=n-1:\quad&&(n-1)f^{(n-2)}(x)+f^{(n-1)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(n-1)}(x)\\ &k=n:\quad &&nf^{(n-1)}(x)+f^{(n)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(n)}(x) \end{align}

Next, consider the exact same list, but this time, I will color code a pattern that we can take advantage of to eliminate many of the terms:

\begin{align}&k=1:\quad &&f^{(0)}(x)+\color{blue}{f^{(1)}(x)I(x)}=\sin^{(1)}(x) \\&k=2:\quad && \color{blue}{2f^{(1)}(x)}+\color{green}{f^{(2)}(x)I(x)}=\sin^{(2)}(x)\\&k=3:\quad &&\color{green}{3f^{(2)}(x)}+\color{red}{f^{(3)}(x)I(x)}=\sin^{(3)}(x)\\&k=4:\quad &&  \color{red}{4f^{(3)}(x)}+\color{lime}{f^{(4)}(x)I(x)}=\sin^{(4)}(x)\\& \cdots \\&k=n-1:\quad&&\color{violet}{(n-1)f^{(n-2)}(x)}+\color{brown}{f^{(n-1)}(x)I(x)}=\sin^{(n-1)}(x)\\ &k=n:\quad && \color{brown}{nf^{(n-1)}(x)}+f^{(n)}(x)I(x)=\sin^{(n)}(x) \end{align}

Now, as you look at all of the diagonally related terms that have the same color, they adhere to the following general pattern:

$$f^{(i)}(x)I(x) \text{ From the lower derivative term } \ \land\ (i+1)f^{(i)}(x) \text{ From the higher derivative term }$$

We can take advantage of this as follows:

Starting with the $k=2$ line, multiply by $(-1)^1\frac{1}{2} I(x)$. Then, adding the $k=1$ line to the $k=2$ line produces:

\begin{align}&f^{(0)}(x)+f^{(1)}(x)I(x)+(-1)^1\frac{1}{2}I(x)\left(2f^{(1)}(x)+f^{(2)}(x)I(x)\right)=\sin^{(1)}(x)+(-1)^1\frac{1}{2}I(x)\sin^{(2)}(x) \\ \text{Is equivalent to} \\&f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^1\frac{f^{(2)}(x)}{2}I^2(x)=\sin^{(1)}(x)+(-1)^{1}\frac{1}{2}I(x)\sin^{(2)}(x) \\ &\end{align}

Let us refer to this new expression as an **updated** $k=2$ line. Next, let us multiply the $k=3$ line by $(-1)^2\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot I^2(x)$ and add this to the **updated** $k=2$ line:

\begin{align} &f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^1\frac{f^{(2)}(x)}{2}I^2(x)+(-1)^2\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot I^2(x)\left(3f^{(2)}(x)+f^{(3)}(x)I(x)\right)\\&=\sin^{(1)}(x)+(-1)^1\frac{1}{2}I(x)\sin^{(2)}(x)+(-1)^2\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot I^2(x)\sin^{(3)}(x) \\ \text{ Is equivalent to} \\&f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^2\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}f^{(3)}(x)I^3(x)=\sin^{(1)}(x)+(-1)^1\frac{1}{2}I(x)\sin^{(2)}(x)+(-1)^2\frac{1}{2\cdot 3} \cdot I^2(x)\sin^{(3)}(x)\end{align}

Hopefully, you can see how this pattern will continue to propagate up until the final addition, where we will modify the $k=n$ line by multiplying it by:

$$(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}\cdot I^{n-1}(x)$$

and subsequently adding this to the **updated** $k=n-1$ line.

Ultimately, we will arrive at the following formula (the so-called **updated** $k=n$ line), where the left side reads as:

$$f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}\cdot I^{n-1}(x)\cdot  f^{(n)}(x)\cdot I(x) = f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)I^n(x)$$

and the right side reads as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\frac{1}{i!}I^{i-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)$$

Putting this together gives:

$$f^{(0)}(x)+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)I^n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\frac{1}{i!}I^{i-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)$$

Recalling that $x \neq 0$, we can rewrite $f^{(0)}(x)$ as $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and subtract it from both sides. Further, we can multiply both sides by $\frac{n!}{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot I^n(x)}$, which we can write as:

\begin{align} f^{(n)}(x)&=\frac{n!}{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot I^n(x)}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\frac{1}{i!}I^{i-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right)-\frac{\sin^{(0)}(x)}{I^{(0)}(x)}\right] \\&=\frac{n!}{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot I^n(x)}\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{i-1}\frac{1}{i!}I^{i-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{(-1)^{n-1}}\frac{n!}{i!}\frac{I^{i-1}(x)}{I^n(x)}\sin^{(i)}(x) \\&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\end{align}

---

**SECTION TWO**

Let us now explicitly prove the validity of this formula via induction. Letting $n=0$, the base case can be trivially proven. So, let us assume that the claim is true for an arbitrary $n$. Can we demonstrate that it is also true for $n+1$?

If $f^{(n)}(x)$  adheres to our above proposed formula, then \begin{align}f^{(n+1)}(x)=[f^{(n)}]'&=\left[\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right]'\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}\left[I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right]'\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}\left[I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i+1)}(x)+(i-n-1)I^{i-n-2}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right]\\&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i+1)}(x)\right)+\left(\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}(i-n-1)I^{i-n-2}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right)\end{align}

In the following steps, we will make use of some summation symbol manipulations that will allow for a clearer simplification (I will color code to make the steps easier to follow). We start by taking the final indexed term out of the (above) left summation and the first indexed term out of the (above) right summation:

\begin{align}&=\color{green}{(-1)^{n-n}\frac{n!}{n!}I^{n-n-1}(x)\sin^{(n+1)}(x)}+\color{red}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}I^{i-n-1}(x)\sin^{(i+1)}(x)\right)}\\&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}(i-n-1)I^{i-n-2}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right)+\color{blue}{(-1)^{0-n}\frac{n!}{0!}(0-n-1)I^{0-n-2}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)} \\&=\color{blue}{(-1)^{0-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{0!}I^{0-n-2}(x)\sin^{(0)}(x)}+\color{red}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-n-1}\frac{n!}{(j-1)!}I^{j-n-2}(x)\sin^{(j)}(x)\right)}\\&+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-n}\frac{n!}{i!}(i-n-1)I^{i-n-2}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right)+\color{green}{(-1)^{n+1-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)!}I^{n+1-n-1-1}(x)\sin^{(n+1)}(x)} \quad (*_1)\end{align}

The summations in the middle can then be combined. For the moment, let us specifically isolate these summations and simplify them separately from the overall equation:

\begin{align} &=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[I^{k-n-2}(x)\sin^{(k)}(x)\right]\times \left(\color{purple}{(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}+(-1)^{k-n}\frac{n!}{k!}(k-n-1)}\right)\end{align}

Looking specifically at the terms colored in purple, note that this is equivalent to:

\begin{align}&=(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}+\frac{-1}{-1}(-1)^{k-n}\frac{n!}{k!}(k-n-1)\\ &=(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}+(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{n!}{k!}(n+1-k)\\ &=(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}+(-1)^{k-n-1}\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}-\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}\right)\\&=(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}\end{align}

Returning to our overall expression $(*_1)$, we have:

\begin{align} &=\color{blue}{(-1)^{0-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{0!}I^{0-n-2}(x)\sin^{(0)}(x)}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}\left[I^{k-n-2}(x)\sin^{(k)}(x)\right]+\color{green}{(-1)^{n+1-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)!}I^{n+1-n-1-1}(x)\sin^{(n+1)}(x)} \end{align}

But this can all be collapsed into a single summation of the desired form:

\begin{align} f^{(n+1)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}\left[I^{k-n-2}(x)\sin^{(k)}(x)\right] \end{align}

---

**SECTION THREE**

There were no special tricks to inspire the general formula for $f^{(k)}(0)$...I simply computed the first several derivatives before deciding that there could be a pattern. The base case is trivial so we will start proving the statement for $k+1$ (assuming that it is true for an arbitrary $k \gt 0$). The inductive case to prove can be formulated as: $f^{(k+1)}(0)=\begin{cases} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{k+2} \quad&\text{ if $k+1$ is even} \\0 \quad &\text{ if $k+1$ is odd} \end{cases}$. Although there are subcases for this proof, we will always use the following framework:

$$f^{(k+1)}(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)-f^{(k)}(0)}{I(x)}$$

Recalling our expression for the $k$th derivative of $f$ at a non-zero $x$, it will actually be more convenient to  rewrite the expression as follows:

$$f^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{i!}I^{i-k-1}(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)=\frac{1}{I^{k+1}(x)}\times \left[\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{i!}I^i(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)\right]$$

Dividing our framework into the two relevant cases (when $k+1$ is even, meaning $k$ is odd...and when $k+1$ is odd, meaning $k$ is even) and considering our more convenient expression, we thus aim to prove the following:

*$k+1$ is even*: $\displaystyle f^{(k+1)}(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{i!}I^i(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)}{I^{k+2}(x)}=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{k+2}$

*$k+1$ is odd*: $\displaystyle f^{(k+1)}(x)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{i!}I^i(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)}{I^{k+2}(x)}-\frac{\frac{(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}}I^{k+1}(x)}{k+1}}{I^{k+2}(x)}=0$

In both cases, the following observation will be important: there is a 4-cycle sequence of derivatives of $\sin$. For example, we have: $\sin^{(0)}=\sin, \sin^{(1)}=\cos, \sin^{(2)}=-\sin, \sin^{(3)}=-\cos$...and, more generally: $\sin^{(4i)}=\sin, \sin^{(4i+1)}=\cos, \sin^{(4i+2)}=-\sin, \sin^{(4i+3)}=-\cos$. This will be relevant information to track so that we can properly assign negative and positive signs throughout our derivations.

Beginning with the '$k+1$ is even' case, we will first work with the numerator $\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i-k}\frac{k!}{i!}I^i(x)\sin^{(i)}(x)$ and convert it into a more useable form. Because $k$ is odd, we know that we will have an equal number of positive signed $\cos$ and positive signed $\sin$ terms...and we will have an equal number of negative signed $\cos$ and negative signed $\sin$ terms. Specifically, we will have:

\begin{align}&(-1)^{(0-k)}\frac{k!}{0!}I^0(x)\sin(x)+(-1)^{(1-k)}\frac{k!}{1!}I^1(x)\cos(x)+\\&(-1)^{(2-k)}\frac{k!}{2!}I^2(x)(-\sin(x))+(-1)^{(3-k)}\frac{k!}{3!}I^3(x)(-\cos(x))+\cdots+\\&(-1)^{(4i-k)}\frac{k!}{(4i)!}I^{4i}(x)\sin(x)+(-1)^{(4i+1-k)}\frac{k!}{(4i+1)!}I^{4i+1}(x)\cos(x)+\\&(-1)^{(4i+2-k)}\frac{k!}{(4i+2)!}I^{4i+2}(x)(-\sin(x))+(-1)^{(4i+3-k)}\frac{k!}{(4i+3)!}I^{4i+3}(x)(-\cos(x))+\cdots +\\& (-1)^{(k-1-k)}\frac{k!}{(k-1)!}I^{k-1}(x)(\pm\sin(x))+(-1)^{(k-k)}\frac{k!}{(k)!}I^{k}(x)(\pm\cos(x)) \end{align}

You will notice that the final line includes the $\pm$ symbol. This reflects two possible scenarios depending on the value that $k$ takes. Specifically, if $k+1$ is divisible by $4$, then this means that $k$th derivative of $\sin$ is $-\cos$. Conversely, if $k+1$ is not divisible by $4$, then the $k$th derivative of $\sin$ is $+\cos$. As long as we keep track of these $\pm$ symbols, we do not need to address these cases separately (the $\pm$ symbol is doing the work for us). Noting that $k$ is odd, observe that the $(-1)^z$ term out in front of the $\sin$ or $-\sin$ terms will always be negative (i.e. $z$ is always odd). Similarly, the $(-1)^w$ term in front of the $\cos$ or $-\cos$ terms will always be positive ($w$ is always even).  We can therefore take out a $-\sin$ and $\cos$ from our above expression, which simplifies to:

\begin{align}&k!\cos(x)\left[\frac{I^1(x)}{1!}-\frac{I^3(x)}{3!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-2}(x)}{(k-2)!}\pm\frac{I^{k}(x)}{(k)!}\right] - \\&k!\sin(x)\left[\frac{I^0(x)}{0!}-\frac{I^2(x)}{2!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-3}(x)}{(k-3)!}\pm\frac{I^{k-1}(x)}{(k-1)!}\right]\end{align}

We will now substitute in $k+1$-th degree Taylor polynomial (with remainder) representation of $\cos$ and the $k+2$-th degree Taylor polynomial (with remainder) representation of $\sin$, which gives us:

\begin{align}&k!\left[\frac{I^0(x)}{0!}-\frac{I^2(x)}{2!}+\cdots\color{red}{\pm}\frac{I^{k-1}(x)}{(k-1)!}\color{red}{\mp}\frac{I^{k+1}(x)}{(k+1)!}+R_{k+1,0,\cos(x)}\right]\left[\frac{I^1(x)}{1!}-\frac{I^3(x)}{3!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-2}(x)}{(k-2)!}\pm\frac{I^{k}(x)}{(k)!}\right] - \\&k!\left[\frac{I^1(x)}{1!}-\frac{I^3(x)}{3!}+\cdots\pm\frac{I^{k}(x)}{(k)!}\mp\frac{I^{k+2}(x)}{(k+2)!}+R_{k+2,0,\sin(x)}\right]\left[\frac{I^0(x)}{0!}-\frac{I^2(x)}{2!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-3}(x)}{(k-3)!}\pm\frac{I^{k-1}(x)}{(k-1)!}\right]\end{align}

Before moving on, I think it prudent to emphasize the $\color{red}{\pm}$ symbols that I have color coded. Note that in all other circumstances involving the $\pm$ or $\mp$ symbol, we were referring to the 4-cycle that *started with $\sin^{(0)}$*. In this context, however, the Taylor polynomial of $\cos$ has a 4-cycle that *starts with $\cos^{(0)}$*. Therefore, the $\cos$-starting cycle leads the $\sin$-starting cycle by one. Accordingly, the $\sin^{(k+2)}$ term effectively coincides with the $\cos^{(k+1)}$ term and their signs are equal.

It should be clear that many of these terms will cancel out with one another. To make it more obvious, consider the following rewrite where $P_{k,0,\sin(x)}=\frac{I^1(x)}{1!}-\frac{I^3(x)}{3!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-2}(x)}{(k-2)!}\pm\frac{I^{k}(x)}{(k)!}$ and $P_{k-1,0,\cos(x)}=\frac{I^0(x)}{0!}-\frac{I^2(x)}{2!}+\cdots\mp\frac{I^{k-3}(x)}{(k-3)!}\pm\frac{I^{k-1}(x)}{(k-1)!}$:

\begin{align}&k!\left[P_{k-1,0,\cos(x)}\times P_{k,0,\sin(x)}+P_{k,0,\sin(x)}\times\left(\mp\frac{I^{k+1}(x)}{(k+1)!}+R_{k+1,0,\cos(x)}\right)\right] - \\&k!\left[P_{k,0,\sin(x)}\times P_{k-1,0,\cos(x)}+P_{k-1,0,\cos(x)}\times \left(\mp\frac{I^{k+2}(x)}{(k+2)!}+R_{k+2,0,\sin(x)}\right)\right]\end{align}

Factoring out the $k!$ gives us:

$$k!\left[P_{k,0,\sin(x)}\times\left(\mp\frac{I^{k+1}(x)}{(k+1)!}+R_{k+1,0,\cos(x)}\right)-P_{k-1,0,\cos(x)}\times \left(\mp\frac{I^{k+2}(x)}{(k+2)!}+R_{k+2,0,\sin(x)}\right)\right]$$

If we now divide this expression by $I^{k+2}(x)$ and take $\lim_{x \to 0}$, many of these terms will cancel out because the terms will have $I^j(x)$ where $j \geq 1$...and, obviously, as $x \to 0$, $I^j(x) \to 0$. We are then left with the limit:

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0}k!\left[\frac{\frac{\mp I^{k+2}(x)}{(k+1)!}-\frac{\mp I^{k+2}(x)}{(k+2)!}}{I^{k+2}(x)}\right]&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\mp(k+2)- \mp 1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\&=\mp\frac{1}{k+2}\end{align} where the signage depends on whether or not $k+1$ is divisible by $4$ or not.

**I will not** derive that case where $k+1$ is odd (as this post is already outrageously long), but note that it will make use of a very similar argument. You will end up using a Taylor polynomial (with remainder) of a $k+3$ and $k+2$ degree for $\sin$ and $\cos$, respectively. After several rounds of simplification, you will arrive at:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\mp 1 -(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}}}{k+1}}{I^1(x)}$$

The $\mp$ symbol will coincide with $k$'s divisibility of $4$. Ultimately, you get $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{0}{I^1(x)}$, which simplifies to $0$ following one application of L-Hopital's rule $\square$.